# Minecraft Schedule Command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a datapack in which a gun can be reloaded automatically when mag is emptied.

There is a `reload.mcfunction` that would set the ammo value of the current player to full.

What I want to do is, when the magazine is emptied, I schedule the reload function to reload after 4 seconds. What I did is this. `schedule function namespace:gun/reload 4s` However, after 4 seconds nothing happened. I am confused as to how the schedule function works in general even after checking the wiki page and I can't get the command to work even once.

I even tried this -
in a kill.mcfunction I wrote `kill @s`

```
/execute as PlayerName run schedule function namespace:kill 1t
```

Still, I am intact after a tick.
Can someone help provide a clear syntax of the /schedule command and tell me if I did anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, scheduled functions are not performed by the initiator of the function scheduled, but the system is responsible. Therefore writing kill @s would not do anything for the system will not kill itself. I changed it to kill @a and the function worked.